# Is there a configuration flag for VS Code PHP Intelephense extension to turn off the parameter hinting?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I'm noticing some additional parameter hinting when using VS Code with the Intelephense extension. I see the value in this, but I'm also finding that it adds a bit too much visual noise for me during development. Is there a way to toggle this option via the settings?

[image: example of parameter hinting]

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Extensions` tab on  right side, 
Then type `@installed`
here you can see installed extensions. Just remove the parameter hinting one from there.
I am using `IntelliJ Parameter Hints` for hinting